# How to send URL with a parameters containing commas ", " in angular 7

Tags: angular, api

i have an array of values and i want to send a get request that will have the values as parameters separated by comma  and it should look like this

```
v1/public/users/en/search?users=user1,user2
```

**component.ts**

```ts
params = ['user1', 'user2'];

getUserProfile() {
  let httpHeaders = new HttpHeaders({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' });
  const options = { headers: httpHeaders };
  return this.http.get('v1/public/users/en/' + this.queryUsers + this.params.join(","), options);
}
```

Comment: use query param, dont build url yourself.

Comment: you mean HttpParams ?

Comment: Using HttpParams is one way to do this, yes.

Comment: why the join() is not working ?

Answer (score 0):

Use query params

```js
getUserProfile() {
  let httpHeaders = new HttpHeaders({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' });
  const query = {
      users=this.queryUsers.join(",")
  }
  const options = { headers: httpHeaders ,params:query};
  return this.http.get('http://95.177.160.97/v1/public/users/en/search', options)
```

Comment: Isn't it missing a `}`?

Answer (score 0):

Angular has a handy thing called [HttpParams](https://angular.io/api/common/http/HttpParams).

```ts
params = ['user1', 'user2'];

getUserProfile() {
  let httpHeaders = new HttpHeaders({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' });
  const httpParams = new HttpParams().set('users', params);
  const options = { headers: httpHeaders, params: httpParams };
  return this.http.get('v1/public/users/en/search', options);
}
```